# Suggestion on running report queries on VERY large databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting

We are running databases in SQL Server 2012 with multiple large datasets (some are in the 50M+ records range).  The previous SQL developer designed the queries and optimized them but they still take 2+ hours to run.

He partially worked around this by creating a static table which gets updated every time the queries are run so if the data hasn't changed, the query runs from this summarized table.  The static table gets updated by performing checksums on the relevant tables and updates it if the checksum show the data has changed.

I'm trying to speed up the whole process.  We have designed an in-house GUI to run the queries for managers to be able to run reports themselves but I don't want them to waste 2 hours waiting for a report. I will be reviewing the indexes he was using to see if I can optimize them further and tweak his code as well but I suspect I might only get minimal performance improvement.

I like the idea of the static table for reporting but would like have it updated more frequently (preferably nightly) but since the data can also change depending on tasks, I want to avoid any performance hits.  For example, the team may be loading records overnight.

Any suggestions would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: I think a good measurement is that how much less I/O is needed with the summarized tables vs the original, to see if it makes sense at all. You might also be able to tune the original query, but without any details it's quite impossible to recommend anything.

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  Is the reporting query slow running on the summarized table or from the detail table?  Or is your question how to populate the summarized table quicker?  In other words, I don't know what you want help with.

Comment: The query runs slowing to populate the summarized table which is where the reports are generated from.

Comment: To clarify the question, what I'm asking is the current workflow a good approach and Im just stuck at the wait time to generate a report on that large dataset?  Or is there another approach people have used to report on large datasets (assuming a simple database structure of 3 tables joined at the most)  to produce reports?  Will a NoSQL structure work here? Or Hadoop?